# Open Source CMS for Restaurant

Tags: content-management-system

If you have come across any CMS (.net or php) that can be used for Restaurant business, please let me know. The admin should be able to add new menu items and perform CRUD menus.

Thankyou.

Comment: have you noticed what kind of site this is?

Comment: apologies, still learning to use stack-overflow.

Comment: curryhunter.com is a website i developed and continuing to develop, please have a look. It provides completely hosted solution, and free themes, also you can choose to build your own theme using simple php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using Wordpress would be a good start for a restaurant website. There are even some people using specific modules like Flutter (a CMS extension to Wordpress) that can be used to [manage menus](http://sara-cannon.com/blog/2010/03/27/using-flutter-for-a-restaurant-menu-in-wordpress/). If you look at the Wordpress extension for restaurant, you have [many extensions](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=restaurant).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for you is to use some OSS e-commerce engine.

OpenCart, I think, is the best one. It is simple and extendable.

Link: http://www.opencart.com/